# Not able to select option from div type listbox in selenium C#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

[image: Sample]

Here the `id=popupY8cuUiMiDU` is dynamic.I need to get the Y value from span but there are multiple listbox with the same span attribute taking Y option.
How can I select from listbox as there is no unique attribute?

Comment: You can select using class attribute into the xpath

Answer (score 1):

There're a few options.

1. getting the element by what's not dynamic in its id

   `//div[contains(@id, "popup")]`
2. using CSS

   `.ui-dropdown-panel.ui-widget-content.ui-corner-all.ui.shadow`
3. asking developers to build in a unique test id for you

   e.g. there could be something like `data-test-id=popup`, then you'd use a css selector like so: `[data-test-id=popup]`

---

There could be more options, you can get more creative etc. But I'd keep it as simple as possible, which promotes maintainability and readability.